# trying to draw a clock with ellipses in Java

Tags: java

[image]

I want there to be 12 ellipses so they represent 5 minute intervals around the clock. However every time I change the linApproxLen for the path iterator, it always either draws too many ellipses or 9 ellipses. How can I make these ellipses represent the 5 minute mark?

```
private Ellipse2D ellipse = new Ellipse2D.Double();
public void setClockContour(int w, int h) 
{
 size = (w > h) ? h/6f : w/6f;
 ellipse.setFrame(w/2-size*2-4.5f,h/2-size*2-4.5f,size*4,size*4);
    double linApproxLen = 0.75 * size * 0.258819;              // sin(15 degree)
    PathIterator pi = ellipse.getPathIterator(null, linApproxLen);
    Point2D[] points = new Point2D[100];
    int num_pts = 0;
    while ( !pi.isDone() ) 
    {
        float[] pt = new float[6];
        switch ( pi.currentSegment(pt) ) {
            case FlatteningPathIterator.SEG_MOVETO:
            case FlatteningPathIterator.SEG_LINETO:
                points[num_pts] = new Point2D.Float(pt[0], pt[1]);
                num_pts++;
        }
        pi.next();
    }
    pts = new Point2D[num_pts];
    System.arraycopy(points, 0, pts, 0, num_pts);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that approach will not work regardless of the `linApproxLen` parameter. This parameter only specifies the "flatness" of the line. While this will certainly influence the number of line segments that are returned, the *actual* number will at least depend on the *radius* of the ellipse that you are painting. So even when you manage to return exactly 12 points in one case, changing the radius (that is, the size given as `w` and `h`) will affect the number of returned points.

Computing the positions of 12 points in a circular formation is particularly easy. You can compute the position on the circle with the sine and cosine of the respective angle. The resulting points may then be scaled or moved in order to obtain the desired shape.

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class ClockCirclesTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 0));
        frame.getContentPane().add(new ClockCirclesPanel());
        frame.setSize(400,400);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class ClockCirclesPanel extends JPanel
{
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics gr)
    {
        super.paintComponent(gr);
        Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D)gr;
        g.setRenderingHint(
            RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, 
            RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        int w = getWidth() / 2;
        int h = getHeight() / 2;
        Point2D points[] = computePoints(w, h, 12);

        int cx = getWidth() / 2;
        int cy = getHeight() / 2;
        g.translate(cx, cy);
        for (Point2D p : points)
        {
            g.draw(new Ellipse2D.Double(
                p.getX() - 5, p.getY() - 5,
                10, 10));
        }
    }

    private Point2D[] computePoints(double w, double h, int n)
    {
        Point2D points[] = new Point2D[n];
        double angleDeltaRad = Math.PI * 2 / n;
        for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
        {
            double angleRad = i * angleDeltaRad;
            double ca = Math.cos(angleRad);
            double sa = Math.sin(angleRad);
            double x = sa * w/2;
            double y = ca * h/2;
            points[i] = new Point2D.Double(x,y);
        }
        return points;
    }

}
```